# Using % to jump between braces in vim only works once, then stop jumping (javascript within html file only)

Tags: vim

So I'd like to be able to use % to jump between matching braces and it only seems to work the first time. This behavior seems to be exclusive to Javascript (and CSS) in HTML files. In a Javascript file it works just fine.

Also, it appears to work fine for HTML tags and jumping between < and >. So it's just (), [] or {} in CSS or JavaScript sections of my HTML file.

What code should I share?

Comment: I don't know what's your problem and what you are asking..

Comment: What filetype is it? Which plugins are you running? Does it still happen when you run without any customization? What does it do when it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you mean using % to jump between pairs of {} or () etc. Or do you mean % when using global replacement (:%s/foo/bar/g)?

Comment: And how exactly does it not "work"? From your description, it sounds like you're seeing `%` jump from a `(` to a `)` the first time you type it, then not jumping back to the `(` when you type it again; is that correct? We're unlikely to be able to help without a much more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: % for jumping between matching braces, parems etc. So it works fine in a .js file, but it only works once in an html file with js in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that OP set forth could be solved by making a symlink to the .html file, like so:

```
ln -s index.html index.js
```

Then edit the index.js file, and the index.html file will be automatically updated, as the index.js is only a symbolic link to the index.html file.

You could check the current filetype of a file in vim with `:set filetype?` and you can also force a filetype with `:set filetype=javascript`.

However, this is not very elegant, and a more permanent solution is desirable.

The problem seems to be permanently solved by adding the following line to the end of my `~/.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html set filetype=javascript
```

This will treat all .html-files as .js-files.

If this directive in the `~/.vimrc` does not seem to have any effect when loading the file in vim, you might consider cleaning out the reference to the file in `~/.vim/view`.

I renamed my `~/.vim` directory temporarily to see if the OP's issue was caused by any of the plugins that I had. It appeared that with no plugins the issue was still present, so it's probably a bug in vim. However, as the issue is straightforward to fix permanently as described above, I won't file a report with the vim maintainers. If anyone thinks it should be reported, please go ahead and do so.